# Which grant type of OAUTH 2.0 should I use if the mobile application and authorization server both are my internal application?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pkce

I am new to OAUTH2.0. I have gone through OAUTH2.0 and OPEN ID, From the links I followed I understand the following for grant type use cases -

PKCE is the most recommended way for mobile applications, as simple authorization code can be susceptible to attacks and client secret cannot be hardcoded in mobile application.

CLIENT ID & CLIENT SECRET - For internal APIs.

My mobile application and Authorization server are both in my internal network.

From my understanding till now I have created the flow such as When the user enters username password to my mobile application it is redirected to my authorization server.

My question is do I need PKCE for this use case? As both mobile and authorization server are my internal application. If I implement PKCE, it seems like there are two calls to authorization server, one with code challenge and one with auth code and code verifier, this seems unecessary fir internal applications in my view.

And if PKCE is not needed what can I use intstead or as an alternate?
Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use PKCE as the mobile app should be threaten as a untrusted application (you mobile app is hosted on a device of a user).

PKCE makes sure there is not a man in the middle attack happening.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I understand how mobile device can be vulnerable.
Can I use implicit flow instead? by passing access token in the https header or in the body and not in the url, this way there won't be two calls to the authorization server.

Comment: It is not recommended to use the implicit flow (and some servers prohibit this flow entirely) due to the inherent risks of returning access tokens in an HTTP redirect without any confirmation that it has been received by the client.